# Shopify slate theme styling is not loading

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I want to add react in shopify theme. So I am trying to use slate. I am following [official doc](https://shopify.github.io/slate/docs/create-a-new-slate-project) of slate.

I have created new slate project.

```
yarn create slate-theme my-new-theme
```

And connected with my store

```
 # The myshopify.com URL to your Shopify store
SLATE_STORE={store-name}.myshopify.com

# The API password generated from a Private App
SLATE_PASSWORD=ccf7fb19ed4dc6993ac6355c0c489c7c7

# The ID of the theme you wish to upload files to
SLATE_THEME_ID=32112656003

# A list of file patterns to ignore, with each list item separated by ':' (optional)
SLATE_IGNORE_FILES=config/settings_data.json

# The timeout for upload theme (optional)
SLATE_TIMEOUT=2m
```

But When I start project using `yarn start`.
Everything working fine but css is not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slate uses a local Express server to serve your assets locally. It's a good idea to create a trusted, self-signed SSL certificate on your device so the assets, served via https, are never blocked.

If you inspect you will get this issue.

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

[image]

You need to Create a [self-signed SSL certificate.](https://shopify.github.io/slate/docs/create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Then css will work fine.